# Measure of the image of a function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a non-decreasing continuous function (probably continuous isn't needed). Let $g(x)=f(x)+x$. Does it follow that for any measurable set $S$, $m(g(S))=m(f(S))+m(S)$?

I'm pretty sure it does, but can't figure out how to prove it. This came up while trying to prove Folland 2.1.9.c (where $f$ is the Cantor function and $S$ is the Cantor set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following facts:

1. A measurable set can be approximated from above by open sets.
2. Every open set of reals is a disjoint countable union of open intervals.
3. Since the function $g$ is strictly increasing and continuous, it maps disjoint open intervals to disjoint open intervals.
4. The result holds for open intervals.